# How to use su user -c combined with npm start --prefix?

Tags: reactjs, bash, npm, terminal, sudo

I want to execute the following command:

```
$ sudo su ubuntu -c npm start --prefix /home/ubuntu/my-app/
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following error:

```
> su: unrecognized option '--prefix' 
> Try 'su --help' for more information.
```

How can I fix this? I can't find anything similar on the net.

Answer (score 1):

what about?

```
sudo -u ubuntu -i npm start --prefix /home/ubuntu/my-app/
```

from `man sudo` :

- `-i` login-specific resource files such as .profile, .bash_profile or .login will be read by the shell
- `-u` Run the command as a user other than the default target user

Answer (score -1):

You just need use quotes around your command like this:

```sh
sudo -u ubuntu -c "npm start --prefix /home/ubuntu/my-app/"
```

You can also use su like this if you want to:

```sh
su - ubuntu -c "npm start --prefix /home/ubuntu/my-app/"
```